# inflict change from a "control page" remotely change content from a separate site

Tags: javascript, html, controller, remote-access

I'm attempting to make a "Debate Game" for a family event. I want to have admin control over the score, topics of discussion, team names and so on.

essentially I want to be able to inflict live change onto a site without having buttons on the "participant screen"

I'm using javascript to link a button to an element and scripting that button on a separate html file.

a very basic attempt to inflict change in the javascript to make a change onto the subject-el
second page for buttons:

```html
</head>
  <body>
    <button class="fa-random fa-solid" id="ran-btn" onclick="topic()"></button>
    <script src="debate.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3cca3c12d.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Main html file that the change should appear on

```html
 <nav class="navbar">
      <h1>The Debate</h1>
      <button
        class="fa-random fa-solid"
        id="ran-btn"
        onclick="topic()"></button>
      <h1 id="subject-el"></h1>
    </nav>
```

and this is the js I have. its a topic() set to randomly choose topics from an array I created

```js
function topic() {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * subject.length);
  subjectEl.innerHTML = subject[random];
}
```